# Batch scripting documentation

Tags: documentation, scripting, batch-file

Is there some nice documentation for Windows batch scripting I can download and refer to while offline?

Comment: I guess this could be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can recommend:

> [An A-Z Index of the Windows XP command line](http://ss64.com/nt/).

It is more thorough than `help` and most importantly it provides several examples for each command. Example: [FIND](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html). There are also cross-references to other commands.

For offline reading you can capture the pages by using e.g. [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) (or some other tool that can follow links and down the content). I use Bart Puype's [Wget binary for Windows](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/).

(There is a similar one for [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell): "[An A-Z Index of Windows PowerShell commands](http://ss64.com/ps/)".)

Answer (score 5):

You can always look at the command help by typing one of:

```
<command> /?
help <command>
```

And to see a complete list of default batch commands you just type:

```
help
```

Also, you can look up the commands in Windows Help. Just click on "Start" -> "Help and Support", then search for "cmd reference" and you will get the "Command-line reference A-Z" page in Full-text Search Matches. It's a complete list of all cmd commands (some of the are only available in batch scripts) and other command line applications.

Comment: I already knew about the 'help' and /c, but knowing I've got a full-blown document in my help is pretty neat. I'm going to have to give the win to the other guy though, a .pdf is much more convenient to me...

Comment: After your comment on bitFlipper's answer, I'll wait till after my train-trip home tonight to see who's answer helped better :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using PowerShell instead, if you can.  More power, fewer headaches.  It's the way of the future, scripting-wise.

You sound like you have a lot of learning ahead of you.  If you do that learning in PowerShell instead of batch, you'll be in a better position at the end.

Comment: I would add that PowerShell has good documentation available from the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an 8-page PDF you can print out: [Win32 Shell Scripting Tutorial](http://www.exguides.org/batchFiles.pdf/).

Comment: "Win32 Shell Scripting Tutorial" -- That link is dead

Answer (score 1):

While it's useful to learn batch, sometimes using batch can be quite a hassle, especially when it comes to things like number crunching, text file parsing, HTML parsing, etc., etc. It's better to also equip yourself with knowledge of scripting using languages such as [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) and [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). Natively, you can also learn how to use [VBScript/JScript](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=01592C48-207D-4BE1-8A76-1C4099D7BBB9&displaylang=en). Here is the guide you can download and read offline.

Answer (score 1):

Another

> [Command-line reference A-Z](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490869.aspx)

It seems like all kinds of command line are in the left sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

Google hits, for "windows batch scripting documentation" - first page:

- http://labmice.techtarget.com/scripting/batchfiles.htm
- http://www.allenware.com/icsw/icswidx.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I already did a Google search, also, one of those asks me to register, and the other doesn't have a download option.

Comment: in fact, this page is now on the front page of google for that search. go SO!